# MVC problem with update method and view with primary identity key column in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am making simple app like address book.

I connected my project with SQL database with just one table via Entity Framework. The first row in the SQL table is ID which is primary key and identity field. When I auto generate edit View and try to run it, I got this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Update(Int32)' in 'Akvizicije_App_1_6.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters "

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        Kontakti kontakt = Context.Kontakti.Find(id);

        return View("Update", kontakt);
    }
```

I know there is parameter with int id and it can't be null because it is primary key and identity field.

But I don't know how to solve that problem. If someone can help me.

```
[HttpPost]   
public ActionResult Update(Kontakti model)    
{    
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)    
    {    
        return View("Index", model);    
    }

    Context.Entry(model).State =

    System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

    Context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Details");    
}
```

This is the view

```
@model Akvizicije_App_1_6.Kontakti

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit"; }

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Kontakti</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idKontakt)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zupanija, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zupanija, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zupanija, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Opcina, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Opcina, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Opcina, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostanskiBroj, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostanskiBroj, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostanskiBroj, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NazivNaselja, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NazivNaselja, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NazivNaselja, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NazivUlice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NazivUlice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NazivUlice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KucniBroj, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KucniBroj, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KucniBroj, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.kcbr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.kcbr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.kcbr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Aktivan, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Aktivan)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Aktivan, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImeOsobe, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImeOsobe, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImeOsobe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrezimeOsobe, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrezimeOsobe, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrezimeOsobe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KontaktBroj, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KontaktBroj, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KontaktBroj, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Komentar, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Komentar, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Komentar, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Natrag", "Index") </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }
```

**ROUTE CONFIG**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Akvizicije_App_1_6
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**MODEL FROM SQL DATABASE**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Akvizicije_App_1_6
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class Kontakti
    { 
        [Key]
        public int idKontakt { get; set; }
        public string Zupanija { get; set; }
        public string Opcina { get; set; }
        public int PostanskiBroj { get; set; }
        public string NazivNaselja { get; set; }
        public string NazivUlice { get; set; }
        public string KucniBroj { get; set; }
        public string kcbr { get; set; }
        public bool Aktivan { get; set; }
        public string ImeOsobe { get; set; }
        public string PrezimeOsobe { get; set; }
        public string KontaktBroj { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Komentar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**web config conn string**

```
<connectionStrings>    
<add name="AkvizicijeKontaktiEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SVEN\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AkvizicijeKontakti;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**AND first part of controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    AkvizicijeKontaktiEntities Context = new AkvizicijeKontaktiEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Kontakti> model = (from k in Context.Kontakti

                               select k).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I changed tag. Thanks

Comment: Where are you making the call to the "Update" method? Are you passing an `int` value named 'id'?